# SQL - Secondary index convenience

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a table that shows the users currently connected to a system, but I receive 100 new connections every minute, and also, about 100 users leave the site every minute. If I had to query for a particular column, is it convenient to create a secondary index for that given column? (considering that the table content changes every minute).

Would it make any difference if the query was an aggregation (like the count of users at a given hour)?

Thanks!

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stuff like **indexing** is **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: I would probably say indexing on any column that you query is generally a good idea, regardless of the data changing.  With that said, please do specify the RDBMS.

Comment: If you're talking about **nonclustered** indexes on **SQL Server** - [see my answer to this question on dba.se about when an index will be used (or not)](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33085/at-what-point-does-having-an-index-become-efficient/33089#33089)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create indexes on columns as required by your queries.

Take into consideration that every index you have on a table will increase load on the server for update/insert queries. You must weigh up the performance benefits of having the index with the decrease in performance for modification queries.

Trial and error can be a good approach.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be some rule of thumb for this, but now I get it.